# Apex after install 404 not found The request could not be mapped to any database in Oracle rest data server

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

It's my first time using oracle and I try to use oracle apex so
I start to :

1. install oracle 19c version 19.3
2. install Tomcat9
3. install apex_20.2
4. install ORDS 20.3

after I install ords I unlock apex user and when I enter http://localhost/ords/ URL

I find this error in the picture [image: Picture of error]

and I try to :

1. reinstall apex and ords
2. stop and restart tomcat
3. control the tomcat to start after the oracle service

but nothing solves my problem

update: run ords validate command :

```
update: run ords validate command :

    [*** script: ords_alter_session_script.sql] 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_version.sql] 

Session altered.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_schema_mapping.sql] 
INFO: Configuring ORDS_PUBLIC_USER to map APEX Workspaces and ORDS schemas

Session altered.

Configuring APEX and ORDS schemas for url mapping
Made APEX_PUBLIC_USER proxiable from ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
Made APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER proxiable from ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
APEX_POOL_CONFIG Synonym exists
Created ORDS_METADATA.APEX_WWV_FLOW_POOL_CONFIG as view over
APEX_200200.APEX_POOL_CONFIG


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

INFO: Completed configuring ORDS_PUBLIC_USER to map APEX Workspaces and ORDS Schemas

Session altered.

[*** script: ords_repair_proxy_connect.sql] 
INFO: Checking ords enabled schemas and its proxy user

Session altered.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_alter_schema_no_auth.sql] 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_migrate_grant_priv.sql] 

Session altered.

INFO: Verify if Application Express exists to setup the migration privileges for
ORDS.
INFO: Completed setting up the APEX REST migration privileges for ORDS.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Session altered.

[*** script: ords_validate_objects.sql] 
INFO: 10:40:12 Validating objects for Oracle REST Data Services.
VALIDATION: 10:40:12 Starting validation for schema: ORDS_METADATA
VALIDATION: 10:40:12 Validating objects
VALIDATION: 10:40:13 Validating roles granted to ORDS_METADATA and
ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
VALIDATION: 10:40:13 Validating ORDS Public Synonyms
VALIDATION: 10:40:14 Total objects: 279, invalid objects: 0, missing objects: 0
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     76  INDEX
VALIDATION: 10:40:14      3  LOB
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     14  PACKAGE
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     13  PACKAGE BODY
VALIDATION: 10:40:14      1  PROCEDURE
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     48  PUBLIC SYNONYM
VALIDATION: 10:40:14      1  SEQUENCE
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     14  SYNONYM
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     27  TABLE
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     27  TRIGGER
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     20  TYPE
VALIDATION: 10:40:14      6  TYPE BODY
VALIDATION: 10:40:14     29  VIEW
VALIDATION: 10:40:14 Validation completed.
INFO: 10:40:14 Completed validating objects for Oracle REST Data Services.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_alter_session_script.sql] 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

[*** script: ords_version.sql] 

Session altered.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: You should get ORDS working in standalone before dropping it into Tomcat. Do you have the ords installer log? If so, attach it to the question. You can also try running ORDS validate command, java -jar ords.war validate